# polymer: using a function in a data binding expression

Tags: polymer

One of the properties of my Polymer element is a timestamp:

```
Polymer({
  timestamp: null,
  ready: function () {
    this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  }
});
```

In my markup I need to show a formatted timestamp:

```
<template>
  timestamp={{getFormattedTimestamp()}}
</template>
```

where

```
getFormattedTimestamp: function () {
  return new Date(this.timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZoneName: 'short'});
}
```

But the code above does not update the display when `this.timestamp` changes because Polymer does not know that it needs to call `getFormattedTimestamp` when this happens.

I cannot just put the contents of `getFormattedTimestamp` into the data binding expression because it won't be able to parse it, and I cannot create a computed property either for the same reason.

Is there a way to do it other than creating an auxiliary member variable that holds the formatted timestamp and updating it when the timestamp changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into [filter expressions](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filters) ?

You can have something like this:

```
<template>
  timestamp={{timestamp | getFormattedTimestamp }}
</template>
```

Comment: is there a solution in Polymer 1.0?

Comment: computed properties or functions:

Answer (score 3):

Functions in markup have to refer to the properties they depend on in as their parameters (because Polymer uses these to figure out when to update them).

```
<template>
  timestamp={{getFormattedTimestamp(timestamp)}}
</template>

getFormattedTimestamp: function (timestamp) {
  return new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZoneName: 'short'});
}
```