# I18Next & Polymer: update data-bindings when language changed

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, i18next

In my project, I am using Polymer 1 and `i18next` (And `i18next-xhr-backend`) to implement Internationalization. The basic approach I did (see below) works very well, but when the user changes the language, Polymer data-bindings don't get updated.

The current approach is as follows:

```
const i18next = require('i18next');
const i18nextXHRBackend = require('i18next-xhr-backend');

i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'default'],
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locale/locales/{{lng}}.json',
      crossDomain: false
    }
  }, function(err, t) {
    console.log("Init done...");
});


if (!Polymer || !Polymer.Base) {
  console.warn('CoolI18N needs Polymer to be loaded.');
}
Polymer.CoolI18N = i18next;
Polymer.Base._addFeature({
  myVeryCoolTranslationMethod: function(...params) {
    return i18next.t(params);
  }
});
```

And in my elements I reach the translations like

```
<div>[[myVeryCoolTranslationMethod('application.welcomeMessage')]]</div>
```

or programmatically via

```
Polymer.CoolI18N.t('application.welcomeMessage')
```

The problem is: when I load a new language at run-time (like `de`), it gets loaded as it should, but the data-bindings don't update and all strings are set in `en` or `default`.

`i18next` fires a `languageChanged` event I can catch like this:

```
i18next.on('languageChanged', (newLang) => {
  console.log("language changed to:", newLang);
});
```

And that's exactly the point where Polymer needs to know something changed...

Is there any possibility to achieve, that these data-bindings get notified? I don't want to update every binding manually...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just from i18next side -> you got a callback on i18next.changeLanguage inside that you can trigger whatever does update bindings in polymer (not used polymer yet so not having an idea for that...sorry).

Or bind changeLanguage via https://www.i18next.com/api.html#onlanguagechanged

Sorry can't help for the polymer part...

Comment: Yes, that's true - I geht the `i18enxt.on('languageChanged', ...` event, but that's exactly the point where I don't know how to notify Polymer...

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159625/polymer-using-a-function-in-a-data-binding-expression Polymer is looking at the params for updating functions in data bindings, so maybe you can add the language key as a parameter to the translator calls!?

Answer (score 0):

This is globally problem of bindings. They won't get updated unless they are removed from DOM and again inserted.

In my application I have 1 element (let's call it `my-guidepost`) that stands as root for whole application (index.html is not good approach, since you can't remove it from DOM).

Because I have my own handling of languages in my project, I have file where I am handling everything neccesary for languages. (you have something similiar I guess).

example of function for changing language:

```
localStorage.setItem("lang-info", lang);
this.text = this[lang];
document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector("my-guidepost"));

setTimeout(() => {
    var guidepost = document.createElement("my-guidepost");
    guidepost.id = "app";
    document.body.appendChild(guidepost);
}, 500);
```

Note: I am not using `shadow-dom`

because of this I had to change many things and this is great to resolve before your project starts expandng into something bigger. For example line:

```
var guidepost = document.createElement("my-guidepost");
```

is the deadliest. Try on yourself and you will see. Maybe you got better architecture than me. But if you are in `ready` function pointing on some DOM element it will throw error (because DOM was not even set up. only created in some variable).

I am here to help you in case you run into some problems.

If you need more info just ask

Comment: Thanks for your intention, but I can't remove and re-attach my root-element from DOM since there is a user-handling implemented, that holds the language, the user has chosen. :-(

Comment: mm. I don't know about any other method of how to reinitialize bindings once they have been rendered.  The only thing is refresh whole page. But it's user unfriendly

Comment: Page reload isn't possible as at this point, the user's language isn't known (no autodetect, will be loaded from a database)